# How to make cordova app accept any certificate

Tags: angular, cordova, socket.io, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am writing an Angular app with a Cordova wrapper. I am using socket.io to connect to a remote server via https, but I get an error that there is an invalid certificate.

I generated a self-signed certificate and key and certificate authority. I guess I could install the certificate on my computer and it might accept it. However I want it to work on any device where the app is installed, so I want to app to accept all certificates. Is there any code I can write to make it accept any certificate on the client side? Thanks in advance.

On the client side:
    `this.socket = io.connect('https://13.209.98.14:1794');`

On the server side, it looks like:

```
var app = module.exports = express();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = https.createServer({
     key: fs.readFileSync('./tls/key.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('./tls/cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./tls/ca-cert.pem')
},app);
server.listen(1794);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: You could, but it's a really bad idea, a security hole that you could drive a truck through.

Comment: Could you please tell me a better way? I mainly want to do this for testing, until an actual certificate is purchased. But don't want to spend the money for testing.

Comment: You can get a free certificate at https://letsencrypt.org